# Cannot open database "UmbracoDB.myDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'

Tags: umbraco, sql-server-2008-express

I am receiving the following error:
`Cannot open database "UmbracoDB.myDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.`

Previously to this error everything was running fine. My database is running as a user instance as described at http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/using-umbraco-with-embeded-sql-database-(sqlexpress-user-instance).  What seemed to cause this issue was attaching the DB to SQL Server Studio Express and then unattaching it again (I was resetting the umbraco admin password). Nothing was changed or is different (That I am aware of).

I presume this is some kind of authentication error or database owner error. I have tried adding the user as described at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/ but it did not work for me. I have also tried a few other things that failed with user names/owners, but I am a bit of a noob. :|

I am running windows 2008, Sql Server 2008 Express, the database is for Umbraco CMS.

Thank you for any ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: try to login to the db through management studio. Use the same username/password pair in the web.config also.

Comment: That won't work cause the connectionstring is trying to use Integrated Security, which assumes the identity of the user account running the code - in this instance, the app pool identity, Network Service.

Comment: How do you mean log in through management studio? I can attach it and get into the database without problems that way. This error is one that is displayed in the browser when running the Umbraco install. (Sorry if that is not clear or if I am being a 100% noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this error was go to windows explorer, find the database, right click->properties->security tab->click edit

Then add network services with full control.

What threw me initially was I was trying to add NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and it wasn't finding it. I had to type network service and click search. Yeah, I'm a noob man.

Doing it inside SQL Server Management Studio didn't do anything for me.

Thank you all who read and tried to help with this post and I hope one day this will help someone.